# How to replace values in DataFrame with values from second DataFrame with condition that it selects different column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two DataFrames.
df1:

```
A    |    B    |    C
-----|---------|---------|
25zx | b(50gh) |         |
50tr | a(70lc) | c(50gh) |
```

df2:

```
  A  |  B
-----|-----
25zx |  T
50gh |  K
50tr |  K
70lc |  T
```

I want to replace values in df1. The row that I'm comparing is df2['A'], but the value that I want to put in to df1 is value from the row df['B'].

So the final table would look like:

df3:

```
A    |    B    |    C
-----|---------|---------|
  T  |   b(K)  |         |
  K  |   a(T)  |   c(K)  |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast `df2` to `dict` and use `replace`:

```
print (df.replace(df2.set_index("A")["B"].to_dict(), regex=True))

   A     B     C
0  T  b(K)  None
1  K  a(T)  c(K)
```

Comment: Hi, what would I need to do if I would want to replace whole cell? instead of b(K) to have only K?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about your comment, try `df.replace(df2.assign(A=".*"+df2["A"]+".*").set_index("A")["B"].to_dict(), regex=True)` @bassline_ballerina.